# Comparison between the maximum clique and maximum biclique problem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, clique

It seems to be commonly believed that the maximum biclique problem (on a bipartite graph) is more difficult than the original maximum clique problem. Is there a formal proof for this claim? (For example, a reduction of the maximum clique problem to the maximum biclique problem.)

Comment: Did you see [Lin's](http://www-imai.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~lin/files/biclique.pdf) SODA paper showing fpt reduction from $k$-biclique to $k$-clique?

Comment: I think you mean from k-clique to k-biclique, R B.  Thus establishing W[1]-hardness of k-biclique from the known result for k-clique.

Comment: Thanks a lot R B and Andy! I will look into this SODA paper. Also Thanks Jan for editing the questions!

Comment: Do you mean that proving hardness for the biclique problem is more difficult that proving hardness of the clique problem? or do you refer to the algorithms for solving the problems?

Comment: @IgorShinkar I am referring to the problem itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the recent W(1)-hardness result for the parametrized complexity of the biclique problem (pointed out by R B), [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X03003330) is a paper whose abstract gives some detailed information about the polynomial-time solvability of variants of biclique detection.